# Why can't ./configure find my openssl/ssl.h

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I've been getting this error when trying to push my local postgres db to heroku

> configure: error: header file  is required for OpenSSL

I downloaded and installed OpenSSL.  The directory `/usr/local/ssl` was created as a result of the OpenSSL installation.

I then reinstalled postgres by doing `./configure --with-openssl` but got the same error as above.  Why can't `./configure` find the header files?

I also noticed my `/usr/local/ssl` directory doesn't contain a `lib` or `include` directory...

Comment: Where is `ssl.h`?  Try `locate ssl.h` or `find / -name ssl.h`.

Comment: `ssl.h` exists at `/usr/local/include` and `libssl.a` exists at `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: I tried running `./configure --with-openssl --with-includes=/usr/local/include/openssl --with-libraries=/usr/local/lib` but I get the error "configure: error: library 'ssl' is required for OpenSSL"

Comment: Can you compile a c program that includes `<openssl/ssl.h>` and links to libssl?  It sounds like your c compiler is futzed.

Comment: @NovaDenizen I'm not sue how to do what you're suggesting.  But it looks like this is a bug https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160902061034.15676.31081@wrigleys.postgresql.org